# Eclipse never export .classpath and .project

Tags: eclipse, export

If i export a jar in Eclipse (no runnable Jar) Eclipse is exporting a .classpath and a .project File. How can I uncheck this Files as default?

Answer (score 0):

In the JAR file dialog the files and folders are preselected that have been selected when the export JAR file wizard was called:

- **Select the source folder instead of the project folder** before doing *File > Export...: Java > JAR file* or
- **Right-click the source folder instead of the project folder** and choose *Export...: Java > JAR file*

Comment: Is there no other way to disable it by default?

Comment: In the source code you can see that the [`JarPackageWizardPage` is initialized](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/jarpackager/JarPackageWizard.java?id=e44d6cf0cde7fe2f2a4c30c23ed863ecc2a249e9#n132) with the [current selection](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/jarpackager/JarPackageWizard.java?id=e44d6cf0cde7fe2f2a4c30c23ed863ecc2a249e9#n205). You could suggest it as an improvement to Eclipse.